# I need to make an OR-gate

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

I have 3 kOhms resistors, one voltage (5 V), 2 switches so I can control my input.

Can someone help me?

I need to do like this:

[image]

I have done this so far:

[image]

Comment: That will kind-of-work but the A+B voltage will be, probably, about 1 V below Vcc due to the base resistors and the base-emitter voltage drop. What is it supposed to drive?

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzNNgb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1a. A simple OR solution. 1b. Using the transistors as diodes.*

This solution might be just as good as your own but provides no current amplification. It depends on what your load is but you haven't specified that.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a NOR gate followed by an inverter and should achieve a logic '1' output closer to the supply voltage depending on what the load resistance is. R3 acts as both the collector resistor for Q1 and the base resistor for Q2.

[image: OR gate]

Comment: Can you remove R4 to reduce the component count?

Comment: @Transistor Yes, that would be an improvement.

Answer (score -1):

Well, this is about as simple as it gets. But it really depends what you want from the output.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwPniHm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Tip: to avoid the "schematics-for-the-deaf" appearance you can add 's', 'm' or 'l' before the .png to size the image. You need to remove it again to get the edit link.

Comment: Thanks @Transistor - didn't know that!

Comment: I use my trademark \$ \color {green} {t} \$ to force a reasonable scale on SE's 640 pixel column width.